# how to install virtual environment with venv with a python specific version 3.8?

Tags: python, version

I'M on google collab, and i want to install virtual environment with venv as "python -m venv .venv".
But I want to installwith a python version 3.8.
can't find in the internet any response to this simple request.
Thanks for any help

I tried "!python -m./Image-Background-Remover-Python/.venv python=3.8"
but it's not working.

Comment: I think it’s not possible on colab to install another python version.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

1. `!pip install virtualenv`
2. `!virtualenv venv -p python3.8`
3. `!source venv/bin/activate`

Also, can you please mention why would you like to create a virtual environment in Colab? Goolge-Colab is already a pre-configured runtime environment with most commonly used libraries and packages. Additionally, your virtual environment will be lost after you restart the runtime, so it is not necessary to have virtual environment. You can install the packages you want if you do not find them in Colab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> virtualenv --python="/usr/bin/python3.8" "/path/to/new/virtualenv/"

Note: You also need to install virtualenv first:

> pip install virtualenv